# Solving complex limits with variables

Tags: limits

I understand that in a problem like this: $\lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{x^m-a^m}{x^n-a^n}$ there would be an answer that breaks apart what happens if m is more than n, if m is less than n, and if m and n are equal. But, how do I compute those limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using L'Hôpital's rule on the limit gives
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^m-a^m}{x^n-a^n}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{mx^{m-1}}{nx^{n-1}}=\frac{ma^{m-1}}{na^{n-1}}=\frac{ma^m}{na^n}$$
If $a=0$ the limit is elementary as we just have
$$\lim_{x\to0}x^{m-n}=\begin{cases}0&m\gt n\\1&m=n\\\infty&m\lt n,m-n\equiv0\mod{2}\\\text{undefined}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: So is there no way to solve this if a=0?

Comment: If a=0, then we have $\lim\limit_{x\ to a)\frac{x^m}{x^n} \and\ x^{m-n}$. Then, if m-n = 0, the limit should be 1. If m - n is more than zero, the limit should be 0. What happens if m-n is less than zero? Or am I going wrong in all of this?

Comment: @Hoppy Sorry I forgot to consider the case when $a=0$ which I have now added to my answer. I was thinking that in any case, for $a=0$, the result would be undefined.

Comment: Why does it not equal infinity if m is less than n?

Comment: @Hoppy, it does, but only if $m-n$ is even. Otherwise the limit from the right is $+\infty$, while the limit from the left is $-\infty$, so the limit is undefined. Think of the graphs of $1/x$ and $1/x^2$ to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the quotient as
$$\frac{x^m-a^m}{x^n-a^n}=\frac{x^m-a^m}{x -a}\cdot\frac{x -a}{x^n-a^n}=\frac{\cfrac{x^m-a^m}{x -a}}{\cfrac{x^n-a^n}{x -a}}$$
to make it the quotient of two rates of variation.

Comment: So basically L'Hôpital's rule then?

Comment: I think L'Hospital's rule should be avoided as much as possible. Students seldom check its hypotheses of validity. It's rather the definition of the derivative which is used in my proposed hint.